# Head command deletes part of line

Tags: bash, head

I have a csv file (settings.csv) with the following data (separator is a space):

```
-n $(output_name) 
--outdir “peaks/$(output_name)” 
-g hs 
-f AUTO 
--qvalue 0.05 
--extsize 200 
-B
sample input output_name
sample-chip1 sample-input1 sample1
sample-chip2 sample-input2 sample2
```

When I call `head -7 settings.csv` I get this expected output:

```
-n $(output_name) 
--outdir “peaks/$(output_name)” 
-g hs 
-f AUTO 
--qvalue 0.05 
--extsize 200 
-B
```

Next I tried to store this output in a variable called `settings` with `settings=$(head -7 settings.csv)` and when I `echo $settings` I get this output:

```
$(output_name) --outdir “peaks/$(output_name)” -g hs -f AUTO --qvalue 0.05 --extsize 200 -B
```

It has deleted the `-n` part of the first line in the settings.csv, and I don't know why. How can I create `$settings` without losing `-n`?

Comment: Quote it `echo "$settings"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `settings` variable already contains the `-n` option you expect to be there. It’s just that the `echo` command interprets it as its own (`echo`’s) option.

One way to avoid this problem is to quote the argument:

```
echo "$settings"
```

Alternatively, you can use

```
printf '%s\n' "$settings"
```